# can we integrate Active Directory with cosmosdb with out any keys

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Can we integrate Active Directory and from there can we access cosmosdb with out any keys, similar like how we access sql server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could know that cosmos db provides two ways of [securing access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/secure-access-to-data).

- Master keys:Used for administrative resources: database accounts,
  databases, users, and permissions
- Resource tokens:Used for application resources: containers,
  documents, attachments, stored procedures, triggers, and UDFs

Generally, we use master key to call the method of cosmos db which needs account key and account name. If you want to provide access to resources in your Cosmos DB account to a client that cannot be trusted with the master key,you could consider using resource token. It is described as below pic:

[image]

Another idea,you could store your cosmos db into [Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-overview),it could keep your key's security no matter it is in the sdk code or REST API.

Comment: thank you so much for the details, can you please help me out in this, apart from the above methods instead of sharing any resource keys can we integrate with Ad and do the validation there it self..